# SASS smart alternate link underline on hover

Tags: css, sass

and if a link is underlined, i want it to get rid of the underline on hover. If a link has no underline, i want it to get one on hover.

Is there a smart way to do this with SASS rather than hard coding it for every link?

Comment: Don't you have two classes already to make some links underlined and some not? You could just use those classes.

Comment: Use two classes, SASS can't be aware of final inherited styles on an element.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, to do this within CSS or SASS this is something that requires a default style for links and a class or data attribute that must be applied to alternative links.

The type of auto-smart styling is possible with javascript though if that's an acceptable alternative. I made a quick jQuery Fiddle that would work by checking all links for the text-decoration style. This has performance drawbacks due to scanning the DOM for all links every page load. It also breaks the law of keeping styling with the CSS realm so it's up to you if it's worth it.

```
var links = $('a');

links.each(function (i) {
    var $this = $(this);

    // if this has underline
    if ($this.css('text-decoration') == 'underline') {
        $this.hover(
          function() {
            $this.css('text-decoration', 'none');
          }, function() {
            $this.css('text-decoration', 'underline');
          });
    } else {
        $this.hover(
          function() {
            $this.css('text-decoration', 'underline');
          }, function() {
            $this.css('text-decoration', 'none');
          });
    };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ym8s6Lwh/